# Finding index number for a character of a particular word in the string

Tags: python, string

Here is the problem. The problem is using python.

```
string = "I am Nirman"
```

Here we have the character 'a' in two words: "am" and "nirman"

So I use the string.index() function to determine the position of character 'a' in the string

```
Function carried: string.index('a')
Returned value: 2
```

This only returns the value of `'a'` in the word `"am"`.. but i want to find the position of letter `'a'` in the word `"nirman"` with respect to the string.

So if i carry out a function, the position of `'a'` in the string is returned `as = 9`.. which is the position of a in Nirman

WHAT TO DO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`index` finds the first occurrence.  To find the last, use `rindex`:

```
>>> String = "I am Nirman"
>>> String.rindex('a')
9
```

If you wanted to find all occurrences, you might use:

```
>>> [i for (i, c) in enumerate(String) if c == 'a']
[2, 9]
```

To find a letter within a specific word, add another condition to the `if` clause:

```
>>> s = 'I am a superman, what are you'
>>> n = s.index('what')
>>> [i for (i, c) in enumerate(s) if c == 'a' and n <= i <= n+len('what')]
[19]
```

Comment: What if there is a string like 

string="I am a superman, what are you"

and i want to specifically find the index of 'a' in the word "what".. what to do then?

Comment: Use the `split` method first then follow the answer provided by @John1024. For example: `[ x.index('a') for x in "I am a superman, what are you".split( ' ' ) ];`

Comment: can you please elaborate upon the split method

Comment: @kenthamlin Updated comment, sorry about that.

Comment: Find the index of `what` and add two.

Comment: for multiple occurence you can also use regex: `[m.start() for m in re.finditer('a', String)]`